# How to Change colour of slide number in libre office

Tags: colors, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer, libreoffice-impress

I was preparing one PPT in libreoffice impress. I was facing problem with slide number color. It was barely visible to eye (number at bottom-right light-blue). Is there anyway to change color and size of slide number?

[full view of slide of templete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzQS2.png)

[Number on the slide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqxqS.png)

Comment: Is the number inside a text-box?

Comment: no. it is default slide number. 
insert -> header and footer -> slide number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Right click on the textbox containing the number, select Character.

[image: IMG:]

2. On the Fonts tab, select the font size.

[image: IMG:]

3. On the Font Effets tab, on the Font Color section, select the color. Click OK.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: is there anyway to change all at a time?